# Limiting value of elements in an array (VBA)

Tags: arrays, vba, max, min

I have an array of numbers, say `[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10]` and I want to set a limiting value that all numbers over this value are set to - eg. a limiting value of 5 would produce `[1 2 3 4 5 5 5 5 5 5]`.

I'm looking to do this on a much larger scale and I need to loop through a large number of times; 
what's the most efficient a least resource-hungry method of doing this? I could loop over it but is there an in-built/more efficient way?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The obvious way would be to loop over the array as you mentioned.  Did you try it, and was it too slow?  Otherwise, it's difficult to make any suggestions without more details.  Why do you need to do this, and how many times on what size of array?

Comment: Tim, I could loop over it - I amended the post to reflect this. I'm looking for any in-built/low level ways of doing it that are more efficient.

Comment: when do you want to set the limiting number? before the first item is added to the array or afterwards?

Answer (score 0):

Add a class to your project that only allows values to a preset maximum.

Right click **ThisWorkbook** in the VBE's Project Explorer and choose Insert ►  Class module. Paste the following into the new code sheet titled something like *Book1 - Class1 (Code)*.

```
Option Explicit

Private pVAL As Long
Private Const maxVAL As Long = 5  'set the maximum value here

Public Property Get val() As Long
    val = pVAL
End Property

Public Property Let val(Value As Long)
    If Value > maxVAL Then
        pVAL = maxVAL
    Else
        pVAL = Value
    End If
End Property
```

The maximum allowed value is set by a `const` at the top of the page. This allows you to change it in one place rather than searching for a hard-coded value in several places. With an eye to your sample data, I've used a `long` type. You may wish to switch to another numerical variable type declaration. When that has been pasted in, open the VBE's Properties window (<kbd>F4</kbd>) and rename the class. My example uses **maxVAL**.

In a module sheet, paste the following test code.

```
Sub classTest()
    Dim a As Long, mVals() As New maxVAL, sVal As New maxVAL

    sVal.val = 3
    Debug.Print sVal.val
    sVal.val = 11
    Debug.Print sVal.val

    ReDim mVals(1 To 10)
    For a = LBound(mVals) To UBound(mVals)
        mVals(a).val = a
    Next a

    For a = LBound(mVals) To UBound(mVals)
        Debug.Print mVals(a).val
    Next a

End Sub
```

Run the sub and check the VBE's Immediate window for the results. They should be similar to the following.

```
classTest
 3 
 5 
 1 
 2 
 3 
 4 
 5 
 5 
 5 
 5 
 5 
 5
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that's appreciated. I will try it out and see how it goes.